# PHP No Value Passed

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to understand why when this page loads, there are no values for the $member['memberName'] and $member['memberDOB'] objects.  Appreciate any help in advance, still learning php and MySQL. :)

Here's the HTML:

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>Player Name</th>
            <th>Player Date of Birth</th>
        </tr>
        <?php foreach ((array)$members as $member) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $member['memberName']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $member['memberDOB']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

    </table>
```

And the PHP:

```
} else if ($action == 'view_team_members') {
$team_id = filter_input(INPUT_GET,'team_id');
$team_name = get_team_name($team_id);
$members = get_team_members($team_id);
include('/view/team_members.php');
}
```

And here's the function:

```
function get_team_members($team_id) {
global $db;
$query = 'SELECT * FROM members
          WHERE teamID = :team_id';
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->bindValue(':team_id', $team_id);
$statement->execute();
$statement->closeCursor();
$members = $statement->fetch();
return $members;
}
```

Comment: It seems you're missing the actual if condition before your
} else if ...
Can you clarify, or add the complete if {} else if {} else {} statement

Comment: That's the index.php which houses all of the $action statements for the site.  I only posted the one that relates to this particular entry, in hopes of not having anyone going cross-eyed by reading my noob code.

Comment: Why are you closing your cursor before the fetch (in get team members)?

Comment: In your DB library (whatever it is), are you supposed to `closeCursor()` right before `fetch()`?

Comment: When I remove the closerCursor(); the page generates:

Warning: Illegal string offset 'memberName' on:

    <td><?php echo $member['memberName']; ?></td>

Comment: To be clear, it generates that warning message in the correct location, and for both the 'memberName' and 'memberDOB' respectfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing with it a few more hours, I changed the fetch() to fetchAll() - which solved the problem (along with removing the closeCursor() ).

```
function get_team_members($team_id) {
global $db;
$query = 'SELECT * FROM members
      WHERE teamID = :team_id';
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->bindValue(':team_id', $team_id);
$statement->execute();
$members = $statement->fetchAll();
return $members;
}
```